# Possible number of throws in nonagonal dice (ie. two nine-sided dice)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have two nine-sided die. Or, in other words, a single pair of nonagonal dice.

I was hoping someone could help me with two questions….

1. How many combinations can be possibly thrown (in a single throw)?

Additionally, on each of the nine faces or facets, there are three different images - ie. three small pictograms allotted per side.

How these two sets of three images combine (and their meaning) will depend on how each of the die fall. (ie. like tarot, the interpretation is subjective but nonetheless counted)

2. So, how many “possible readings" can be construed in total?

Comment: Are the dice distinguishable?

Answer (score 2):

If you can distinguish the dice, there are $9^2=81$ throws.  If not, and each die has one to nine spots you can have results of $2$ to $18$ spots, which are $17$, though they are not equally probable.  Question 2 is not well defined enough to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

> let N(k) be the no.of possibilities of getting k as output.
>   then N(k)=k-1 for all k from 2 to 10
>   and N(k)=N(20 - k) for all 10 k from 11 to 18.